# Faster test for maximum order elements mod p for highly composite p-1

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

A common test to see if $a$ is a generator mod $p$ is to factor $\phi(p-1) = q_1^{e_1}\cdots q_k^{e_k}$, and for every prime factor $q_i$ to check that

$$a^{(p-1)/q_i} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

doesn't hold for any $q_i$. Now for the prime I'm interested ($p = 2^{61}-1$) we find that $\phi(p-1)$ has actually many prime factors (12), and thus we would need to repeat the above test 12 times. To speed this up I had the idea of combining these tests by re-using the same $a, a^2, a^4, a^8 \dots$ factors found by exponentiation-by-squaring for all tests. To speed it up further I had the idea of using a slightly different test:

$$a^{m(p-1)/q_i} \equiv a^{m(p-1)/q_i \bmod p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

Where $\gcd(m, p - 1) = 1$. This test is equivalent, as when $a^m$ is a generator, $a$ must be as well and vice versa. Then we can choose multiplier $m$ such that $m(p-1)/q_i \bmod p-1$ has fewer $1$-bits on average in the binary representation, reducing the amount of multiplications needed during exponentiation-by-squaring.

Finding one such constant $m$ that reduces the number of ones for all 12 $q_i$ is hard. **Could this idea be further improved by choosing a different multiplier $m_i$ for each test?** What conditions would such a set of $m_i$ have?

Comment: If you haven't yet, you should consider using Montgomery multiplication for further speedup.

Comment: @OscarSmith I don't think Montgomery multiplication helps. Modular reduction is already very fast since $p = 2^{61} - 1$ is a Mersenne prime and thus we can reduce $x$ using the identity $x \equiv 2^{61}\lfloor x / 2^{61}\rfloor + x \bmod 2^{61} \equiv \lfloor x / 2^{61}\rfloor + x \bmod 2^{61} \pmod p$.

Comment: you're right. That will be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use individual $m_i$ as long as $\gcd(m_i, p-1) = 1$. We prove the equivalence of each test independently, in both directions:

$$a^{(p-1)/q_i} \equiv 1 \pmod p  \implies a^{m_i(p-1)/q_i} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

This is obvious, as $a^{m_i(p-1)/q_i}\equiv {(a^{(p-1)/q_i})}^{m_i} \equiv 1^{m_i} \pmod p$.

$$a^{m_i(p-1)/q_i} \equiv 1 \pmod p \implies a^{(p-1)/q_i} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

Let's write $ x = a^{(p-1)/q_i}$ and suppose $x \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$. We know that $x^{m_i} \equiv 1$ and thus that $x$ is a non-trivial $m_i$-th root of unity. But $m_i$ is coprime with the order of the multiplicative group which violates Lagrange's theorem. Thus our assumption that $x \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$ was wrong and we conclude $a^{(p-1)/q_i} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.